# How to avoid Maven Versions on Siblings Submodules?

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

I have a Maven structure such as:

```
- Parent
  - Child 1
  - Child 2
```

I have defined the `Parent` `<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>` and left `Child 1` and `Child 2` without versions, this way both children will inherit the `Parent` version automatically.

The problem is, I need to reference `Child 1` as a dependency to `Child 2`, and the only way to do it is to pass `Child 1` version, such as:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.myapp</groupId>
    <artifactId>child-1</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

I wanted to avoid this, since both children will inherit the `Parent` version anyway, but I can't include `Child 1` as:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.myapp</groupId>
    <artifactId>child-1</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

**Is it there a way to avoid referencing `Child 1` verion on `Child 2` POM?**

Getting this automatically will be a lot less error-prone.

Comment: Not really sure you can. What problem do you want to avoid? The mvn release plugin will take care of updating all versions of your child modules including those that are also referenced as dependencies in other child modules. So that part certainly isn't error prone.

Comment: I want to avoid forgetting to update Child 1 version, inside Child 2 POM..... For what you just said, then this will never be an issue? If I define Child 1 version as 1.0 in Child 2 POM... Then I make a modification on the Parent version, to 2.0, and I forget to update Child 1 to 2.0 in Child 2 POM, Maven will ignore the 1.0 version on the POM and use 2.0 instead?

Comment: @DB5 what you mentioned is what's in the posted answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you can do that.

Parent `pom.xml`:

```
<groupId>com.acme</groupId>
<artifactId>root</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<modules>
    <module>child-1</module>
    <module>child-2</module>
</modules>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.acme</groupId>
            <artifactId>child-1</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.acme</groupId>
            <artifactId>child-2</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
<dependencyManagement>
```

And then just reference siblings without versions:

Child 1 `pom.xml`:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.acme</groupId>
    <artifactId>root</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<artifactId>child-1</artifactId>
<name>Child 1</name>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.acme</groupId>
        <artifactId>child-2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Child 2 `pom.xml`:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.acme</groupId>
    <artifactId>root</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<artifactId>child-2</artifactId>
<name>Child 2</name>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.acme</groupId>
        <artifactId>child-1</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Explicit parent version in children is not a problem as both `mvn versions:set` and Maven Release Plugin can handle that.

Comment: Interesting... And `${project.version}` is available in Maven 3.3.9? Because that's the version shipped with IntelliJ IDEA (which they never update, I have no idea why)

Comment: Yes, it's a [standard Maven property](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Properties).